# RoR Devise sign up with either email or username

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a RoR apps which uses Devise for user registrations and session management. As of now the users can signup using email and I use :confirmable in devise so that a confirmation email is sent and user account will be activated. 
But now I want to add a option to user to register either with email or username so that i have to confirm if he uses email and no confirmation is required if he is not providing email..

Can i achieve this using devise..?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the bottom of this wiki page:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-:confirmable-to-Users

You should be able to do something like this:

```
protected
def confirmation_required?
  # Insert custom logic about confirmation only if a user has an email
end
```

Place this in your `User.rb`